# Why do I receive a mouseevent constantly even when I don't move my mouse in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Both `movementX` and `movementY` are 0. Is this a bug/feature of Chrome? I've tested firefox, it works as expected.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => console.log(ev));
// or
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => console.log(ev.movementX, ev.movementY));
```

Comment: I just tested this and had no unexpected events.  Have you tried in Incognito to check it isn't an installed browser plugin?

Comment: Keep your mouse outside console for about 4 second and it should happen. That should not be caused by a plugin because electron has the same problem. @kyranjamie